# SQLite UPSERT failed when using with SELECT

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I can not use the syntax `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...ON CONFLICT...DO UPDATE SET`  with my temporary table.
This is tested on Python 3.8.7 with sqlite3.sqlite_version = 3.33
Can someone guide me the syntax that works or the version of SQLite3 that works for this issue.

This is my table, the temporary/staging table also has the same column structure.

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stocks(
            id integer PRIMARY KEY,
            ticker TEXT NOT NULL,
            year INTEGER NULL,
            financial_date DATE NOT NULL,
            record_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            price REAL NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT unq_mytable UNIQUE(ticker,year,financial_date)
            )''')
```

Insert into using `Values` is fine tested by the command below

```
    sql = f"""
INSERT INTO stocks 
(
    id,ticker, year, financial_date, record_timestamp, price
) 
VALUES
(
    3,'XYZ',2020,'2020-01-13','2010-07-28 15:36:56.200',77.55
)

ON CONFLICT (ticker,year,financial_date) DO UPDATE 
SET
    record_timestamp = excluded.record_timestamp,
    price = excluded.price
;
"""
c.execute(sql)
```

But when I put the data into my temporary table(staging) then try to UPSERT, this syntax is fail.

```
    sql = f"""
INSERT INTO stocks 
(
    id,ticker, year, financial_date, record_timestamp, price
) 
SELECT
    id,ticker, year, financial_date, record_timestamp, price
FROM stocks_stg

ON CONFLICT (ticker,year,financial_date) 
DO UPDATE SET
    record_timestamp = excluded.record_timestamp,
    price = excluded.price
;
"""
c.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, because you are using `INSERT ... SELECT...` instead of `INSERT ... VALUES...`, the parser can't distinguish if the `ON` keyword is used for the `ON CONFLICT` clause or it is used for a join.
This is a documented problem in [SQL As Understood By SQLite/UPSERT/Parsing Ambiguity](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html), where the proposed workaround is to use a `WHERE true` clause right after the `FROM` clause and before the `ON` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO stocks 
(
    id,ticker, year, financial_date, record_timestamp, price
) 
SELECT
    id,ticker, year, financial_date, record_timestamp, price
FROM stocks_stg
WHERE true
ON CONFLICT (ticker,year,financial_date) 
DO UPDATE SET
    record_timestamp = excluded.record_timestamp,
    price = excluded.price
;
```